# Semantically/accessibly correct use of <details> for an image caption?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup

I have some very long image captions, I would like to use the `<details>` tag to accommodate these. But I'm not sure how to semantically/accessibly associate details with images in the same way as, for example, `figcaption` and `figure`.

What is the correct way to do this?

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/150/100/nature" alt="Epcot theme park" />
<details>
  <summary>Epcot theme park</summary>
  <p>Epcot is a theme park at Walt Disney World Resort featuring exciting attractions, international pavilions, award-winning fireworks and seasonal special events.</p>
</details>
```

Here the alt text and summary title are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically associate contents of the `<details>` element with an `<img>` element by using the `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` elements as shown in the example:

```
<figure>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/100/nature" alt="Alt text that's different from your summary">
    <figcaption>
        <details>
            <summary>Epcot theme park</summary>
            <p>Epcot is a theme park at Walt Disney World Resort featuring exciting attractions, international pavilions, award-winning fireworks and seasonal special events.</p>
        </details>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

The `<figcaption>` element accepts [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content), which includes the `<details>` element.

You may also be interested to review the [W3C Web Accessibility Tutorials for Complex Images](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/complex/), as there's some very relevant info there.

Comment: Great but why the `role="group"` does it not break the `<figcaption>`? Either way +1 I am just not sure on that part?

Comment: Roles can be handy but in this case it causes the `<figure>` element to **not** be announced as a figure element. **Without** the `role`, NVDA will say, *"**figure** graphic Alt text..."*. **With** the `role`, NVDA will leave off *"figure"*. In general, it's best not to change the semantics of a natively semantic element (https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#second).  But it's a good answer, otherwise.

Comment: @slugolicious -- I was a little unsure about the role myself, but that's how it's presented in the W3C example (see link from my post). I couldn't find any adverse consequences of it being there, so I left it.  I also tested using NVDA. Regardless of leaving off the word "Figure", the response from NVDA is intelligible and makes sense.

Comment: This technique is outlined as part of WCAG 2.2 in ARIA 17: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/aria/ARIA17.html

Comment: @Josh That's for form controls. It's not relevant in this context. `role="group"` should not be used in this context.

Comment: @sean -- Do you have anything to back up that statement? WCAG 1.3.1. gives examples that are not form controls. Also, Chrome seems to be performing an accessible name computation on the `<details>` element, which would seem to suggest that at least one major browser interprets this element as a "user interface component" as established in WCAG. https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG22/#dfn-user-interface-components

Comment: Edited my answer to remove role=group. Although I'm not convinced that it's incorrect, I don't think that having it adds much (if any) benefit for real-world end-users.